# Segmentation Fault preventing Heroku Commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm using Ruby 2.1.2

When I put that in my gemfile I get errors on heroku commands that say I'm using 1.9.3

When I remove it from my gemfile I get a "segmentation fault" regarding the json gem:

```
/Users/Justus/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

I just want to run a migration on heroku and this is preventing me from running any heroku commands. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd be happy to add more detail if I had any idea where to begin?

Comment: first provide your Gemfile that is causing the issue, Gemfile.lock too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the solution (thanks to [Nitin Verma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3918072/nitin-verma) https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/400):

```
# Rakefile
task :freedom do
  Bundler.with_clean_env { sh "heroku" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as did a lot of others, you can see everyone talking about it in [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/932).

Regardless, you need to update the heroku toolbelt to 3.7.5 at a minimum.  You can check which version you have by doing:

`heroku version`

If you're not up to date you can run:

`heroku update`

then check the version to make sure it's at leaste 3.7.5