# All Heroku Commands Are Broken due to Ruby Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Everytime I run a heroku command I receive this error:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
```

This has been happening since I pushed several changes (adding sidekiq and making changes to my clock.rb file, also: a new model I need to migrate the db for)

Does anyone know why this might be happening? It only started after I added ruby '2.1.2' to the gemfile. But before that I was getting [this funky segmentation fault error](https://gist.github.com/justuseapen/9c80bb2e117c08293e51).

Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'clockwork'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'parse-ruby-client'
gem 'parse_resource', '~> 1.8.0'
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'foundation-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'valid_attribute'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'thin'
end
```

Comment: What does `ruby --version` give you? It sounds like you have Ruby 1.9.3 installed, but you're asking for 2.1.2 to be used. Try upgrading to 2.1.2 locally.

Comment: Yeah I have 2.1.2 locally: ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Comment: Yeah... Nothing in there is helpful?

Comment: Can you run `heroku run "ruby -v"` and tell us the output?  @BroiSatse is pointing out that your path might be set correct as that link shows you why you might be recieving that error.

Comment: I did, EVERY `heroku` command returns this: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2

Comment: Then what is your PATH?  `heroku config -s | grep PATH`

Comment: Again, ALL heroku commands return "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2", so I can't check the path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's seems to related bundler issue. Go through here https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/400 same sort of issue also here get fixed with :

```
# Rakefile
task :freedom do
  Bundler.with_clean_env { sh "heroku" }
end
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks I added this to my rakefile but I'm not sure what to do with it?

Comment: Now try run your your rake commands. Did it also getting this error?

Comment: create a rake task like `task :whatever do
  Bundler.with_clean_env { sh "heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate --app #{app}"}
end`

Comment: THANK YOU! IT WORKS! YAYYY! If you want, collect the bounty on this question with that same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584197/segmentation-fault-preventing-heroku-commands

Answer (score 0):

I had two applications using Ruby.  In your terminal, change to the directory of the application, then check the Ruby version you are using.  Update it appropriately.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean. I've only got 2.1.2 on my machine. I hadn't set the ruby version in my gemfile until recently in response to this segmentation fault error: https://gist.github.com/justuseapen/9c80bb2e117c08293e51